# docker vs kubernetes in jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

I am new to docker and kubernetes, so I was reading a pipeline code that pulls a docker image, that will be used as an agent.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'myinternalrepo/myimage:1.0'
            
        }
```

in another pipeline it is written in a differnet way, and cant tell what is the difference

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes{
            yaml """
            spec:
  containers:
    - name: myimage
      image: myinternalrepo/myimage:1.0
```

so what is the difference between both? though I am getting the same containers and when running some commands on each container I get same results.

Comment: One is Docker and the other is Kubernetes, that’s the difference. Usage probably isn’t different, but how and where it’s run is.

Comment: ummm I needed more details about the difference of both implementations, when reading the console output, for example when using docker it stops the docker image and then removes it  at the end of the pipeline. while that doesn't seems to be happening in kuberetes case.

Answer (score 0):

Agent Docker means that your pipeline will be executed inside the docker container running **on Docker host**. That means that your agent needs to have **Docker configured**. In other words, it usually means that your agent has the Docker Daemon running.

Agent Kubernetes means that your pipeline will be executed inside the (docker) container running inside Kubernetes Pod **in Kubernetes**. That means that your agent needs to have (access to) Kubernetes configured.

So, technically, your pipeline will work the same, but the difference is how your Jenkins agents are configured.

For more details, please check https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent